# CSS Responsive Container to Text

Tags: html, css

I am still relatively inexperienced in programming, which is why I am asking this question.

I have a section with a `background image`, and text in it; the text also takes the space it needs, but the `background image` unfortunately does not match the text, better said it has no height at all and does not appear. I am talking about the CSS class .discord-background. What should I do?

```css
section#discord {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  top: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section#discord .discord-background {
  position: relative;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(../img/Screenshot\ 2022-03-19\ 085352.png);
  min-height: fit-content;
  height: auto;
}

section#discord .discord-background-cover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.65;
  background-color: #3572D8;
  z-index: 2;
}

section#discord .discord-text {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  text-align: left;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 1% 5% 1% 5%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 4;
}

section#discord .discord-text-image {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(../img/mtf.png);
  min-width: 120px;
  min-height: 216px;
  background-size: auto;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

section#discord .discord-text-content {
  font-size: 150%;
  line-height: 1.9em;
  color: #000;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social {
  display: grid;
  border: none solid;
  border-radius: 1%;
  margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 125%;
  line-height: 1.9em;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #363e4b;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social>div {
  background-color: #5f27cd;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social .title {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  text-align: center;
  grid-row: 1;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social .a {
  text-align: center;
  grid-row: 2;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social .b {
  text-align: center;
  grid-row: 3;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social .c {
  text-align: center;
  grid-row: 2;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social .d {
  text-align: center;
  grid-row: 3;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social .e {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  text-align: center;
  grid-row: 4;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social .e .discord-area button {
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #5372F0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  font-size: 18px;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social .e .discord-area .button_icon {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social .e .discord-area button:hover {
  background: #5678ff;
}
```

```html
<section id="discord">
  <div class="discord-background-cover">
    <!--The cover for the background picture-->
  </div>
  <div class="discord-background">
    <!--The background picture of the discord section-->
    <div class="discord-text">
      <div class="discord-text-image">

      </div>

      <div class="discord-text-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione veniam alias totam cumque expedita voluptatum facere aperiam recusandae dolores libero molestiae eligendi nesciunt in magnam possimus rem, quam, est quod autem perferendis iste eius labore
        beatae. Illum veniam, rerum perferendis repellat reiciendis aspernatur quibusdam voluptatem incidunt earum aut enim commodi?
      </div>

      <div class="discord-text-social">
        <span class="title">Discord</span>
        <span class="a">Online</span>
        <span class="b">
                        50 <i class="fa-solid fa-signal"></i>
                        </span>
        <span class="c">Mitglieder</span>
        <span class="d">
                        100 <i class="fa-solid fa-user-group"></i>
                        </span>
        <span class="e">
                            <div class="discord-area">
                                <button id="discord-submit" type="discord" name="Discord-Login">

                                    <span class="button_icon">

                                        <i class="fa-brands fa-discord discord"></i>

                                    </span>

        <span>UGN</span>

        </button>
      </div>
      </span>
      <!--<span class="e">Link</span>-->
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you please create a   Minimal, Reproducible Example ->https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please remove the [tag:php] content and replace that with a small sample of the HTML that's sent to the browser, since **a)** php is irrelevant to the browser, and **b)** CSS operates on the HTML that's seen by the browser (php is not sent to the browser).

Answer (score 0):

You should look into css: background-image

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

---

Is this what you're looking for?

```css
section#discord {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  top: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section#discord .discord-background {
  position: relative;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(../img/Screenshot\ 2022-03-19\ 085352.png);
  min-height: fit-content;
  height: auto;
}

section#discord .discord-background-cover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.65;
  background-color: #3572D8;
  z-index: 2;
}

section#discord .discord-text {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  text-align: left;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 1% 5% 1% 5%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 4;
}

section#discord .discord-text-image {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(../img/mtf.png);
  min-width: 120px;
  min-height: 216px;
  background-size: auto;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

section#discord .discord-text-content {
  font-size: 150%;
  line-height: 1.9em;
  color: #000;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social {
  display: grid;
  border: none solid;
  border-radius: 1%;
  margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 125%;
  line-height: 1.9em;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #363e4b;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social>div {
  background-color: #5f27cd;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social .title {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  text-align: center;
  grid-row: 1;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social .a {
  text-align: center;
  grid-row: 2;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social .b {
  text-align: center;
  grid-row: 3;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social .c {
  text-align: center;
  grid-row: 2;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social .d {
  text-align: center;
  grid-row: 3;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social .e {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  text-align: center;
  grid-row: 4;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social .e .discord-area button {
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #5372F0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  font-size: 18px;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social .e .discord-area .button_icon {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

section#discord .discord-text-social .e .discord-area button:hover {
  background: #5678ff;
}

.discord-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.discord-background img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section id="discord">
  <div class="discord-background-cover">
    <!--The cover for the background picture-->
  </div>
  <div class="discord-background">
    
    <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/Discord_IAP_KeyVisuals_Header_02.jpeg?w=1390&crop=1">

    <div class="discord-text">
      <div class="discord-text-image">

      </div>

      <div class="discord-text-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione veniam alias totam cumque expedita voluptatum facere aperiam recusandae dolores libero molestiae eligendi nesciunt in magnam possimus rem, quam, est quod autem perferendis iste eius labore
        beatae. Illum veniam, rerum perferendis repellat reiciendis aspernatur quibusdam voluptatem incidunt earum aut enim commodi?
      </div>

      <div class="discord-text-social">
        <span class="title">Discord</span>
        <span class="a">Online</span>
        <span class="b">
                        50 <i class="fa-solid fa-signal"></i>
                        </span>
        <span class="c">Mitglieder</span>
        <span class="d">
                        100 <i class="fa-solid fa-user-group"></i>
                        </span>
        <span class="e">
                            <div class="discord-area">
                                <button id="discord-submit" type="discord" name="Discord-Login">

                                    <span class="button_icon">

                                        <i class="fa-brands fa-discord discord"></i>

                                    </span>

        <span>UGN</span>

        </button>
      </div>
      </span>
      <!--<span class="e">Link</span>-->
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your approach, but unfortunately it still doesn't fit the text.
https://imgur.com/a/KOxpqy4

Comment: What i would do in this instance is 1. set a height similar to the text, it wont be perfect, but it will work. Or 2. Set height manually with media queries